# Python - Generate random dates to create Gantt sequenced tasks

Tags: python, random

The idea is to generate random but sequenced dates based on workload estimation in python.

The goal is to have an output like this:
**Task**,  **Start_date**, **End_date** 
task1, 01/06/2020, 05/06/2020 
task2, 08/06/2020, 11/06/2020 
task3, 12/06/2020, 24/06/2020 
...

So I started to work on this code but unable to find a way to randomize it.

```
#startdate
start_date = datetime.date(2020, 1, 1)
#enddate
end_date = datetime.date(2020, 2, 1)
time_between_dates = end_date - start_date
days_between_dates = time_between_dates.days
#workload in days
random_number_of_days = random.randrange(days_between_dates)
random_date = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=random_number_of_days)
```

Any idea on how to randomize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a seed:

```
random.seed(a=None)
```

a is the seed value. If it is None then the system time is used by default. Add this line before you start generating random dates. Don't set the seed inside a loop because that causes bugs.

You can do something like this:

```
import datetime
import random
# startdate
start_date = datetime.date(2020, 1, 1)
# enddate
end_date = datetime.date(2020, 2, 1)
time_between_dates = end_date - start_date
days_between_dates = time_between_dates.days
#workload in days

random.seed(a=None)

tasks = 10

for i in range(tasks):
    random_number_of_days = random.randrange(days_between_dates)
    random_date = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=random_number_of_days)
    print("Task" + str(i+1) + "," + str(start_date) + "," + str(random_date))
    start_date = random_date # by @Makram
```

You will need to change what start date is, too, unless you want all of them to start at the same date.

You can make a list of startdates and then index them with i. This will allow you to have a specific start date for each of the tasks.