# Generate list of random datetimes in ISO8601 format in Python

Tags: python, datetime, random, iso8601

I want to generate a list of length n with random datetime strings in Python within a range.

```
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime(2019,1,1,0,0,0).astimezone().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat()
end = datetime.datetime(2019,12,31,23,59,59).astimezone().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat()
```

[I had asked a similar question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65735262/generate-a-random-list-of-n-dates-in-the-iso-8601-format-within-a-range-in-pytho), but I did not use the correct format for datetime.What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You seem to be aware of how to format to iso format string; how to generate the random date has basically been answered under your linked question and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62140629/python-generate-random-dates-to-create-gantt-sequenced-tasks) I think. To get a list of random dates, you simply have to add a list comprehension or append to a list in a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying the answer here for your format: https://stackoverflow.com/a/553448/7942856

```
from random import randrange
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

start = datetime(2019,1,1,0,0,0).astimezone().replace(microsecond=0)
end = datetime(2019,12,31,23,59,59).astimezone().replace(microsecond=0)

n = 5

def random_date(start, end):
    """
    This function will return a random datetime between two datetime 
    objects.
    """
    delta = end - start
    int_delta = (delta.days * 24 * 60 * 60) + delta.seconds
    random_second = randrange(int_delta)
    return start + timedelta(seconds=random_second)

random_dates = [random_date(start, end) for i in range(n)]
```

Outputs:

```
[datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 6, 2, 25, 32, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=39600), 'AUS Eastern Summer Time')), datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 5, 13, 2, 15, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=39600), 'AUS Eastern Summer Time')), datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 24, 15, 57, 19, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=39600), 'AUS Eastern Summer Time')), datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 3, 9, 35, 8, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=39600), 'AUS Eastern Summer Time')), datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 12, 14, 33, 35, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=39600), 'AUS Eastern Summer Time'))]
```

Then if you want the text ISO format, simply call `.isoformat()` on your list elements.

```
[random_date(start, end).isoformat() for i in range(n)]
#['2019-05-03T22:06:56+11:00', '2019-12-31T06:56:09+11:00', '2019-03-09T05:07:59+11:00', '2019-03-24T09:24:42+11:00', '2019-01-08T03:23:31+11:00']
```

Comment: Awesome this is just what I need. Thank you!